# Image not showing in for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to display the image and name in a for loop on my template.

This is what I have on my template for loop, and I thought it should work, but it doesn't

```
{% for op in tracked_objects %}
           {%  if op.is_mine %}
           <div style="float:left;">
               <div>
                   <img src="{{ op.tracked_object.image }}" alt="">
                    <a href='{% url track-profile op.tracked_object.id %}'>{{ op.tracked_object }}</a><br>
               </div>
           </div>
           {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know that op.is_mine is true because the Name shows.

Here is my views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
   user = request.user
   tracked_objects = user.tracked_object_perms.all().order_by('is_mine',)
   context = {
       'tracked_objects':tracked_objects,
   }
return render_to_response( 'accounts/profile.html' , RequestContext(request, context))
```

and finally the models.py

```
name = models.CharField(max_length='140')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/tracked_object_images', null=True, blank=True)
```

**Update**

Now when I use the below anser of adding the .url onto the end, I get three broken image icons.  Now I have checked the path and it goes to the correct image.   Would this be a server issue possibly?  Or something along those lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<img src="{{ op.tracked_object.image.url }}" alt="">
```

Comment: would it have something to do with my localhost not showing images or something?  Because by theory, your answer SHOULD work

Comment: No, running the built-in server on localhost shouldn't affect it. What do you have your MEDIA_URL set to? and where in the project are your static files served from?

Answer (score 0):

See [Using django.contrib.staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#using-django-contrib-staticfiles).